# HTTPS api call not working with sha2 ssl

Tags: ssl, https, sha

I have used an external api which can be accessible via `https (sha1 ssl)`, And now the external api system upgraded to `sha2`. While I am hitting the api, i am getting below exception.

```
Connecting to test.demo.com|10.200.100.101|:8443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish `SSL connection`.
```

## Update:

Comments from external api team (earlier we used SSL protocol and now TLS (TLSv1.2) is benign used in new setup (SSL was expired protocol)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on description above (without actual code snippet) you need to check if you client application has appropriate protocol specified (if they changed it on server to TLS v1.2, you need to change it in your client as well). [Great link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/87284) regarding different TLS versions.

Comment: Thanks. we are using Jboss 7.1.3 CE and have changed the configuration in standalone as follows <ssl name="my-ssl" key-alias="test.my.ssl" password="pwd" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/test.my.ssl.keystore" protocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>. Is there anything should be consider at OS (Redhat 5.10) level also?